# TFS 2010 project structure and getting the best out of it

Tags: version-control, continuous-integration, projects-and-solutions

we recently decided to move to TFS 2010. we would like also to improve our source control structure and projects structure.

here is the structure the team agreed on:

```
 |OurCompanyName (or common root name)
 |
 +--Windows
 +----Applications
 +------App1
 +------App2
 +----Services
 +------WindowsService1
 +------WindowsService2
 |
 +--Web
 +----Applications
 +------WebApp1
 +------WebApp2
 +----Services
 +------WebService1
 +------WebService2
 |
 +--Common
 +----ThirdParty
 +----Libs
 +------DataAccessLib
 +------BusinessLogicLib
 |
 +--Tests
 +----TestProject1
 +----TestProject1
```

The common folder holds 3rd party and our in-house libraries which is used all-over(App1,App2,WebApp1...etc)

We need to acheive the following :

- Release versions must depend on latest production release of Libs.
- if tests failed, depended projects shouldn't build and team should be notified.
- simple branching: development, production,versioned releases and how we can structure them accordingly.

I have already read the following guide [Visual Studio TFS Branching Guide 2010](http://tfsbranchingguideiii.codeplex.com/) but it only addresses the branching bit of it.

Comment: @syneptody Thanks for the comment.
it is a TFS project collection but there are multiple projects. do you recommend having more that a project collection ?

Answer (score 0):

You aren't really asking a question from what I can tell. But I can give some feedback/discussion on your goals.

- Release versions must depend on latest production release of Libs.

A release version should depend on whatever it used while it was being developed. Not whatever the current version is.  You may want to go into more depth on what this requirement is and why you think you need it.

- if tests failed, depended projects shouldn't build and team should be notified.

TFS doesn't support chaining builds out of the box, you can modify the build template to add support, but it's not a particularly clean solution (imo).

You can self subscribe to failing builds utilising the built in tfs alerts subscriptions, however it is up to each developer to do so. (Unless you subscribe a mailing group or create a custom event mailer).

Again why are you automatically updating dependencies in other projects? surely you'd be better off using a pull for updates than a push and use a technology like NuGet to handle your references.

- simple branching: development, production,versioned releases and how we can structure them accordingly.

That sounds like simply branching each time you do a release, which is very simple.

If you however knew which changeset you releases you wouldn't have to branch and could branch only if you needed it (eg to fix a production bug).  It takes a lot more work as you either need to manually label your code on release (at which point you gain nothing over branching) or have an automated release process which does it for you.

**Other notes**

You dont' want to use multiple Team Project Collections - this adds in a nightmare when it comes to managing build servers.

You may want to update your diagram to show what is a Team Project, Branch, and what is just a standard folder.

Answer (score 0):

Having used TFS for a while, I would like to give a caution:
You look at things from the developer's side, as we did when we started thinking about how to best deploy the projects. However, you should also take under account project management requirements.

Having different TFS projects, means different reporting data to the manager.

Thus if App1 and WebApp1 are to the person that runs your projects part of the same overall project, then if you have them in different TFS projects, questions of the form: 'How many hours did my team spend on this project' will be difficult to answer.
I would seriously look into this issue before deciding on the project structure.

Now regarding your questions:

- Release versions must depend on latest production release of Libs

As Betty (above) mentions this is not good practive. What will happen if development took place with production release of Lib v1.0 and sometime during stabilization Lib changed to v2.0 ?

- if tests failed, depended projects shouldn't build and team should be notified.

I believe this is a matter of your build script, not of your layout

-simple branching

We try to implement a simple MAIN-line based approach,where we have one or more development branches (depends really on your specific requirements). 
Once in a while, when dev code is considered 'stable' i.e. passed basic unit tests, it is merged onto the MAIN line. Developers carry on, on their development branches whereas code on the MAIN line goes more extensive testing. Bugs found are reported and fixed initially on the DEV branches and merged back onto the main line. Once code on the MAIN line is good enough, stabilization starts on a RELEASE branch. After that point, bugfixes take place on the RELEASE branch and merged back into the MAIN line. Note that 'stable', 'good enough' are values that mean different things to organizations.